# How to reduce an array of Int Publishers on Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I have an array of Int plublishers being changed via network and I'd like to assign the sum of it to a variable.
So far I came up to this:

```
cancellable = Publishers.MergeMany(items.map { $0.$count } ).sink { value in
           print(value) 
        }
```

It is printing all the values, but what I really want is to reduce all of them into a single value and then assign to somewhere else. But when I try to do a reduce, something like:

```
   cancellable = Publishers.MergeMany(items.map { $0.$count } )
            .reduce(0){ counter, value in
                counter + value
            }.sink { value in
                print (value)
            }
```

it doesn't work anymore, the value is never printed. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Edit:

This seems to work, but it doesn't look very efficient

```
cancellable = Publishers.MergeMany(items.map { $0.$count })
      .sink { _ in
          let value = self.items.map { $0.count}.reduce(0) { counter, newValue in
              counter + newValue
          }
          print(value)
      }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "an array of Int publishers"? Combine `reduce` does not operate until the _last value_ has arrived. In what sense do these publishers emit a _last value_?

Comment: I noticed that if I add a printer inside the reduce, it keeps printing forever. I only have 2 publishers in my example, both with $count = 1, so the total should be 2.
But If I leave the app running, the print goes forever, always adding the last value + new one to infinity. It seems the reduce doesn't know when all publishers were collected but I don't know how to signal that

Comment: @matt see my comment. I think this is the problem, I don't know how to tell reduce that all publishers were "collected".

In my example above, `items` has 2 objects with a:
@Published private(set) var count = 0

What I want to do is to check all items, sum the count and get the result.

Comment: @matt it never emits the last value, it keeps polling forever. I just want the sum of all of them in one point in time.

Comment: Well there’s your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `reduce` operator reduces all values into an accumulator. It emits the accumulator once as its sole output, which only happens upon completion of the upstream publisher.

I suspect what you're looking for is the [`scan`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/scan(_:_:)) operator. It's similar to `reduce`, but emits the accumulator at every event.

Comment: I tried that but it has the same problem as reduce, it keeps adding the values forever.
Instead of adding all available items, for example, 1+1, then 1+1 again, it does
1+1, then 2+1, 3+1, forever.
I'd like the "loop" to start over once it sums everything. See my edited code, that works, but it's inefficient

Comment: @Wak Well that's a totally different question, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. I guess I didn’t mention the fact that I want the sum of the values in one point in time instead of a continuous sum. My bad.

Comment: @Wak Unfortunately, nothing comes off the top of my head to solve your second problem, besides implementing a custom operator. I can't think of a composition of existing operators that could achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Your last edit where you sum up all the values at the end is actually the most straightforward approach that should work for most typical cases.

It's only inefficient if you're considering really high numbers because for each new value of any publisher, you're summing over the values of all publishers - an O(N) time operation.

So, *purely as an intellectual exercise*, to improve efficiency, the only way to do this in O(1) time is to update some accumulated sum by adding the current value and subtracting the previous value *of the same publisher*.

```
let initialSum = items.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.count })

// publishers of tuples of: (current, previous)
let publishers = items.map { $0.$count.scan(($0.count, 0), { ($1, $0.0) }) }

let cancellable = Publishers.MergeMany(publishers)
                      // add current, subtract previous
                      .scan(initialSum, { $0 + $1.0 - $1.1 } )
                      // the first run will produce duplicates of initial sum
                      .removeDuplicates()
                      .sink{ print($0) }
```